# How to assign luigi parameter using list in task wrapper

Tags: python, luigi

I am using luigi to extract different user actions and save each as a csv simultaneously.

The idea to look at my source data, find unique actions and create csv's using the names of each of those actions.

```
class data_filter(luigi.Task):
        task = luigi.Parameter()
        def run(self):
                data_filter = full_file[full_file['properties_url'].str.contains(task)]
                data_filter.to_csv('/Users/Documents/Data/'+str(task)+'.csv')
        def requires(self):
                return []
        def output(self):
                return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/Documents/Data/'+str(task)+'.csv')
#chaining tasks with wrapper
class wrapper(luigi.WrapperTask):
        def requires(self):
                file = pd.read_csv('/Users/Desktop/attr.csv')
                actions = file.utm_source.unique()
                task_list = []
                for current_task in actions:
                        task_list.append(data_filter(task=current_task))
                return task_list
        def run(self):
                print ('Wrapper has ended')
                pd.DataFrame().to_csv('/Users/Documents/Data/wrangle.csv')
        def output(self):
                return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/Documents/Data/dwrangle.csv') 
if __name__ == '__main__':
    luigi.run(wrapper())
```

The wrapper should tie everything up by, looking at all unique actions, assigning them to task_list and running task_list...while assigning the current task I am iterating through to task = luigi.Paramter in my data_filter class.

However this returns the error message:

```
  return luigi.LocalTarget('/Users/emmanuels/Documents/GitHub/Springboard-DSC/Springboard-DSC/Capstone 1 - Attribution Model/Data/'+str(task)+'.csv')
NameError: name 'task' is not defined
```

and

```
===== Luigi Execution Summary =====

Scheduled 1 tasks of which:
* 1 failed scheduling:
    - 1 wrapper()

Did not run any tasks
This progress looks :( because there were tasks whose scheduling failed
```

I just want to figure out what I am doing wrong

Comment: Try using `self.task`. Parameters value are instance variables of the task.

Comment: Should post this as an answer.